# Docker possibly causing my packages to bug out?

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm

I am using docker to deploy a reactJs project I have taken over, I have run into an issue not only on my copy but on all others who use the project: I cannot use any new packages...

So there are already existing packages in use that work a charm but for any new ones I introduce (for example `react-CSV`) it installs via npm absolutely fine, I import it to the required js file, `ctrl + click` takes me to the source code but on using `docker compose up` I get the following:

[image]

I have spoken with a colleague and he too believes it's a docker issue however we both have little exposure to it.

Files for reference:

package.json

```
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "*",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.3.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.1",
    "react-csv": "^1.0.19",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.2",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "redbox-react": "^1.3.0",
```

The import:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import Modal from '../../Modal';
import Calendar from '../../../../../../lib/components/Calendar';
import formatPrice from '../../../../../../core/formatPrice';
import s from './SeasonalCustomers.scss';
import react-csv from 'react-csv'; ***** HERE *****

import {
  fetchSeasonalCustomersReportData as fetchSeasonalCustomersReportDataActionCreator,
  exportSeasonalCustomerReport as exportSeasonalCustomerReportActionCreator,
  REPORTS_SHOW_SEASONAL_CUSTOMERS,
} from '../../../actions/reports';

let selectedFromDate;
let selectedToDate;
```

docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - node-modules:/app/node_modules
      - ./tmp:/data/tmp
    command: bash -c "npm start"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - DATABASE_URL=**********************
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis/0
      - WEB_PROCESSES=1
      - WORKER_PROCESSES=1
      - MANDRILL_API_KEY=****************
      - SMTP_FROM_ADDRESS=***************
      - HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED=TRUE
      - BASE_URL=******************
  # worker:
  #   build:
  #     context: .
  #     dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
  #   volumes:
  #     - .:/app
  #     - node-modules:/app/node_modules
  #   command: /app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec /app/node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets=es2015 -- src/worker.js
  db:
    image: "postgres:9.5.3"
    environment:
      # POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: ticketsystem
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  redis:
    image: "redis:4.0.0-alpine"

volumes:
  node-modules: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at the mounts of your docker-compose.yaml, this part in particular:

```
volumes:
  - .:/app
  - node-modules:/app/node_modules
```

You load in your current folder, but cancel out node modules, which will be an empty folder within your container. This is the reason why running `npm install` or `yarn install` again will fix your application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok- I have a solution however I still am at a loss as to why this is the case, including `npm install --save prop-types` in the start script did the job, if anyone could explain why this fixed it, would be grateful.

Comment: Looks like you just forgot to run `npm install`. can you show your docker-compose configuration?

Comment: Hi there, I used to have npm install included inside my start script but removed it as it wasted time and had already been run. What could have happened for me to have to run it again? Updated with docker-compose.yaml fyi :)